# How to prove this inequality (like triangle inequality)

Tags: inequality, triangles

**[Question]**
$$
\left|\sqrt {x^2+y^2}-\sqrt {x^2+z^2}\right| \le |y-z|
$$

**[My Effort]**
$$
\begin{align}
&I_1=\sqrt {x^2+y^2} \le |x|+|y|\\
&I_2=\sqrt {x^2+z^2} \ge \left||x|-|z|\right|\\
\implies\\
&I_1-I_2 \le |x|+|y|-\left||x|-|z|\right|=\begin{cases}
|y|+|z|, &\mbox {if }(|x|\ge|z|)\\
2|x|+|y|-|z|,&\mbox {if }(|x|<|z|)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Either way, I can't reduce to $|y-z|$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the (so called inverse) triangle inequality in $\mathbb R^2$ applied to the vectors $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$:
$$\left|\sqrt {x^2+y^2}-\sqrt {x^2+z^2}\right|=\left|\|(x,y)\|_2-\|(x,z)\|_2\right|\leq \|(x,y)-(x,z)\|_2\\
=\|(0,y-z)\|_2=\sqrt{0^2+(y-z)^2}=|y-z|$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The result is obvious if $x=0$. If $x\ne 0$, multiply top and bottom on the left by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$ ("rationalize" the numerator). Then use the fact that $\frac{|y+z|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}\le 1$.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good. "top and bottom", what does that mean?

Comment: Oh, I saw "multiply" as "multiple"... I see what you mean. I tried that, no luck. Mind some details?

Comment: I had a typo in an earlier comment. Using my suggestion, the new top is $|y-z||y+z|$. And we have $|y+z|\le |y|+|z|$, while $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\ge |y|+|z|$.

Comment: You are welcome.  The answer by Svetoslav is less computational, and I think better.